# Can I remove Apple Domain Verification file after verifying domain?

Tags: stripe-payments, applepay

I have set up Apple Pay through Stripe integration. I had to drop a file into `/root/.well-know/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association`

Everything is working now. My question is can I now remove this from the filesystem entirely, or will Apple be pinging it every once in a while?

I have already removed it and payments go through fine, I'm just wondering if it might break in the long run?

Comment: Is there any reason *not* to leave it in place? It costs you nothing to leave it there; having payments suddenly fail will.

Comment: @ceejayoz Sure there could be. One might be one codebase and multiple websites, like with Magento.

Comment: @MagentoAaron If you're running a multi-tenant system, you presumably have enough know-how to serve a per-tenant file for this scenario. OP gives no indication they're in that sort of case.

Comment: did you find the answer for this quesiton ?